# Any way to find the list of webpages I added to homescreen from Chrome Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser, samsung-galaxy-s-8

I had to disable Chrome Android on my phone today due to an unrelated software install issue. In the process, all the webpages I had added to my homescreen on my S8 phone from Chrome Android disappeared.

Is there somewhere I can find a history of all the pages I added to my homescreen? There were like 18 pages and I can't remember them.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the information you are looking for is simply lost. The shortcuts that a user adds to the homescreen are saved inside the default home launcher's data directory. Typically, it is a database (named launcher.db or similar to it), usually within a table often named "favorites".

I checked the relevant database (for Nova Launcher) after adding some Chrome shortcuts to the homescreen, and then disabled Chrome, and then checked again. The relevant entries were no longer there, and they were also not restored when I enabled the app again.

Unless your default launcher was provisioned to be backed up by Google and was indeed backed up recently, or if you manually backed it up (highly unlikely), it would be futile to proceed in this direction any further.

Comment: I have no launcher. Just the default from the phone. So how come disabling Chrome removes the homescreen shortcuts but all the tabs I had open in the browser are still there?

Comment: It doesn't matter which launcher you are using. The home shortcuts are stored by the default launcher, so the answer applies to any launcher you are using as default. As for the tabs, they are not part of launcher app's data but of Chrome browser's data. Disabling an app doesn't delete data or cache of that app. It simply makes the app inaccessible to the user and the apps.